# How prove that $\mathcal{T}^\infty=\mathcal{T}\cup\{U:X\setminus U$ is compact in $X\}$ on $X^\infty=X\cup\{\infty\}$ is a topology

Tags: general-topology, definition, compactness, compactification

Following a reference from "Elementos de Topología General" by Angel Tamariz and Fidel Casarrubias.

> **Definition**
>
> Let be $(X,\mathcal{T})$ a topological space -*generally not compact*- and let be $\infty\notin X$: so we say that the topology $$
> \mathcal{T}^\infty=\mathcal{T}\cup\{U:  X\setminus U\text{ is compact in $X$}\}
> $$
> on $X^\infty:=X\cup\{\infty\}$  is the Alexandroff compactification of the space $X$.

Here an image of my text

[image]

Well I ask how to prove that $\mathcal{T}^\infty$ is a topology on $X^\infty$.

Could someone help me, please?

Comment: I think you want $X\setminus U$ to be *closed* and compact.

Comment: Definitely, the one point compactification has $X\setminus U$ closed and compact. I cannot think right now of an instance where your $\mathcal T^\infty$ is not a topology (namely, of a non-compact space where intersection of compact subsets may not be compact). But I'm sure there are.

Comment: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2787296/alexandroff-compactification-topology) an another user give the same definition I given: anyway as reference I say to you that in "General Topology" by John L. Kelly it is written that $X\setminus U$ must be **closed** and compact in $X$ and not only compact as in the previoius definition.

Comment: Look more closely at your link: it says that $\mathcal T^\infty$ is the set of subets $U\subseteq X^\infty$ such that $U\cap X\in\mathcal T$ (i.e. $U\cap X$ is open in $X$) **and**, if $\infty\in U$, $X\setminus U$ is compact. Therefore $X\setminus U=X\setminus(X\cap U)$ *is* closed in $X$.

Comment: Okay, It's right: so what can I argue?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Okay, so how can one prove that my $\mathcal{T}^\infty$ is a topology?

Comment: Sorry, now I edited the question: specifically I put an image of the definition of my text.

Comment: I put it now: the only problem is that it is in Spanish.

Comment: @Gae.S. For this reason I worte $\mathcal{T}^\infty=\mathcal{T}\cup\{U:  X\setminus U$ is compact in $X\}$

Comment: Sorrry if the image is in Spanish: I am italian and therefore I study books in Spanish rather than English because Spanish is very similar to Italian.

Comment: You have to read the "brackets" differently: the 'y' is between $U \cap X$ open in $X$ and the "o" statement, see my answer. It's a bit ambiguously formulated as it is. They should write a complete logical formula: $(U \cap X \in \mathcal{T}) \land ((U \subseteq X) \lor (X \setminus U \text{ compact in } X))$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So let $$\mathcal{T}^* := \{U \subseteq X^*\mid U \cap X \in \mathcal{T} \land (\infty \in U \implies X \setminus U \mathrm{\ compact)}\}$$

instead (as in the linked question) which does say something different then you had before: An open neighbourhood of the new point $\infty$ is of the form $U \cup \{\infty\}$ such that $U \subseteq X$ is already open in $\mathcal{T}$ **and** $X\setminus U$ is compact (in $(X,\mathcal{T})$ of course).

This is also consistent with the Spanish: you have to read it as ($U \cap X$ open in $X$) and ( either $U \subseteq X$, so $\infty \notin U$  **or** ( $\infty \in U$ and) $X\setminus U$ is compact ). So for any $U$ we have $U \cap X$ is open in $X$ at least. (and this is important for being a compactification, see below). The formulation as I gave it above is more explicit. It shows there are two types of open sets: the old ones from $X$ and new ones of the form $U \cup \{\infty\}$ where $U$ is "old" open and moreover has compact complement in $X$, which is important to show the new space to be compact.

Now if we have a union of such open sets $O_i, i \in I$ there are two cases:

1. $\infty \notin O:=\bigcup_{i \in I} O_i$. So all $O_i \in \mathcal{T}$ and hence so is their union, and $O \in \mathcal{T}^\ast$.
2. $\infty \in O:=\bigcup_{i \in I} O_i$, so for some $j \in I$, $\infty \in O_i$ so $O_j= O'_j \cup \{\infty\}$ with $O'_j$ open in $\mathcal{T}$ and $X\setminus O_j$ compact in $(X,\mathcal{T})$. But then $X\setminus O \subseteq X\setminus O_j$ and this is closed in that compact set (as $O \cap X \in \mathcal{T}$) and hence compact, and so $O$ also is in $\mathcal{T}^\ast$.

The two set intersection axiom is also boring: there are three cases (none of them contains $\infty$, just one of them, or both); all are easily checked. E.g. if $\infty \in O_1, O_2$, then $O_1 \cap O_2 \cap X = (O_1 \cap X) \cap (O_2 \cap X) \in \mathcal{T}$ and $X\setminus (O_1 \cap O_2)  =(X\setminus O_1) \cup (X\setminus O_2)$ is a union of two compact sets, so compact.

And as $\emptyset \in \mathcal{T}$ it is in $\mathcal{T}^\ast$ too and $X^\ast$ has $X^\ast \cap X = X \in \mathcal{T}$ and $X\setminus X^\ast=\emptyset$ is compact, so $X^\ast \in \mathcal{T}^\ast$ too.

Note that for any $U \in \mathcal{T}^\ast$, $U \cap X \in \mathcal{T}$ by definition, and $\mathcal{T} \subseteq \mathcal{T}^\ast$ so that the subspace topology of $X$ as a subspace of $X^\ast$, is just $\mathcal{T}$ again. This is not garantueed to be the case if we just demand that open neighbourhoods $U$ of $\infty$ have $X\setminus U$ compact. And this is an essential property for a compactifcation of $X$! If $X$ is Hausdorff to start with, this is a non-issue, but e.g. take $X=\Bbb Z$ with the cofinite topology on $\Bbb Z^-$ and the discrete one on $\Bbb Z^+_0$ (to make $X$ non-compact) and then your book's construction makes $X$ (as a subspace of your $A^\infty$) a discrete subspace.

Comment: Sorry, why $O'$ is open in $\mathcal{T}$? Then unfortunately I can't prove that if $\infty\in U,V$ then $U\cap V\in\mathcal{T}^*$ and if $\infty\in U\land V\in\mathcal{T}$ then $U\cap V\in\mathcal{T}^*$. Could you prove it? Excuse me, forgive my inability.

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro $O'= O \cap X$. By assumption (in my definition) this must be in  $\mathcal{T}$.

Comment: Okay, this is clear.

Comment: Seguramente, ¡buenas noches!

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro I've added one argument for intersections too.

Answer (score 1):

Let us start by using closed and compact sets. By complements, I mean complements in $X$.

$\emptyset\in\tau\subset\tau^\infty$, and also closed and compact, so $X\cup\{\infty\}\in\tau^\infty$. Suppose $\mathcal{J}=\mathcal{J}_1\cup\mathcal{J}_2$, where $U_j\in\tau$ for $j\in\mathcal{J}_1$ and $U_j\in\tau^\infty\setminus\tau$ for $j\in\mathcal{J}_2$. Clearly, $\bigcup_{j\in\mathcal{J}_1}U_j\in\tau\subseteq\tau^\infty$, as $\tau$ is a topology. Moreover, by de Morgan, $\left(\bigcup_{j\in\mathcal{J}_2}U_j\right)^c=\bigcap_{j\in\mathcal{J}_2}U^c_j$ is closed and compact, so $\bigcup_{j\in\mathcal{J}_2}U_j\in\tau^\infty$, and so $\bigcup_{j\in\mathcal{J}}U_j\in\tau^\infty$. Similarly, if $|\mathcal{J}|<\infty$, we see that $\bigcap_{j\in\mathcal{J}_1}U_j\in\tau\subseteq\tau^\infty$, and $\bigcup_{j\in\mathcal{J}_2}U_j^c$ is compact and closed, so $\bigcap_{j\in\mathcal{J}_2}U_j\in\tau^\infty$. One can then check that the intersection of these intersections is either empty or in $\tau$, and hence in $\tau^\infty$.

Finally, if $X$ is Hausdorff, then compact sets are closed and your book's stuff coincides with that of Kelly's.

Comment: What can we say about $\bigcup_{j\in\mathcal{J}\equiv\mathcal{J}_1\cup\mathcal{J}_2}U$ and about $\bigcap_{j\in\mathcal{J}\equiv\mathcal{J}_1\cup\mathcal{J}_2}U$?

Comment: The union over $\mathcal{J}$ is the union of unions over $\mathcal{J}_i$. Note that the complements of both unions are closed, and their intersection is thus a closed subset of a compact set, and hence compact and closed, so the union is in $\tau^\infty$. The intersection over $\mathcal{J}$ is the intersection of the intersections, and that I addressed already.

Comment: Okay, so why one can then check that the intersection of these intersections is either empty or in τ, and hence in $\tau^∞$?

Comment: The intersection intersection, if not empty, will not contain $\infty$, so it will be in $\tau$ as a finite intersection of open sets.

Comment: Okay. Then how to preve the assertion when $X\setminus$ is only compact?

Comment: If the space is Hausdorff, then compact sets are closed.

Comment: Generally the space in my definition aren't Hausdorff space.

Comment: The added set is closed under arbitrary unions and finite intersections. Take the complements of the unions over $\mathcal{J}_i$ for $i=1,2$. Their intersection will give a closed subset of a compact set, at least in the subspace topology, so that will then be compact. This is also the complement of the union of unions. Similar reasoning for the intersection of intersections. Maybe someone else can fill in the details. It's my bedtime.